# Timer while viewController is displaying?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

While a view is displaying, I need to call a function in its view controller repeatedly - perhaps once every second. If the user moves away from the view (by going down or up the stack in the containing navigation controller) the timer should stop. When they move back to the view, the timer should resume.

How do I achieve this? Is there anything in particular I need to consider (if the user switches out of the app, or takes a call?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` and `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` to set/reset your `NSTimer`.

Comment: Nice, NSTimer and these methods are what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
  NSTimer *timer;

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {

           timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 0.1 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
    }
    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {

          [timer invalidate];
    }

    -(void) targetMethod: NSTimer * theTimer 
    {
           NSLog(@"Me is here at 1 sec delay");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your timer in an array (and other timer if needed).

When yu need to stop the timer use `[theTimer invalidate];`

When yu need to resume it, parse your array timer and fire it/them

if the user change / stop app, it'll not stop the current timer, it'll go to the end, but other timer won't start anymore.